# Node running HTTPS Server?

Tags: node.js

I am writing a program that will serve a particular file. However, I get an exception. I am not sure on the error since I am a bit new to node based programming.

I have got the certificates correct.

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/home/test/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/test/server.crt')
};

tls.createServer(options, function (s) {


content = fs.readFileSync('/home/test/abc.conf','utf8');
s.write(content);
s.setEncoding('utf8');
s.pipe(s);

}).listen(8000);


node app.js
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:800:14)
```

Comment: Its actually 
 ECONNRESET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized, it is quite easy using just https.createServer and provide options of ciphers there.

```
var ciphers = [
    'AES128-SHA',
    'AES256-SHA'
].join(':');



var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),
    ciphers: ciphers

};

https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {

console.log("Running node now"); 

}).listen(443);
```

Since, I am using 443 https standard port, I need to start this node app with admin permission i.e. sudo.